# Is this possible via regex conditional?

Tags: regex, conditional-statements

Suppose I have successfully captured the following groups:

```
/1 "text1"
/2 "notation1"
```

Now, I want to replace `/1` with `"newtext1"` iff `/2` contains `"notation1"`. Is this possible via conditional statement?

Or by any other method?

Comment: Which language are you using? Some allows you to replace a regex by a function so you could just write a normal `if` to do so.

Comment: Let's assume I need to do it purely with regex, without using any language constructs.

Comment: This is from the `regex` tag description on SO: _Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool._.

Comment: For pure regex the answer is: no, you can't. Pure regex consists only of concatenation, | and Kleene star (*), without lookarounds, capturing groups and stuff. But in reality some languages support some other features as well. Therefore it's important to specify programming language.

Comment: why can't you simply put `national1` in the regex? e.g. instead of having `xxxx(.*)yyy(.*)zzz` which gives you two capture groups and you replace based on capture group 2's value, you can simply use `xxx(.*)yyynational1zzz` as regex to do you search and replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex has no conditional statement that allows you to check if a capture group has captured a certain value. You have two options:

1. Change the pattern so that it only matches if it finds `notation1`, i.e. regex=`(text1)(notation1)`, replacement=`newtext1\2`.
2. If your programming language supports it, create a substitution function that checks the contents of group 2 and returns the desired replacement string. For example in python you could do: `re.sub(r'(text1)(notation1)', lambda match: 'newtext1notation1' if match.group(2)=='notation1' else 'text1notation1', 'text1notation1')`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are in perl the substitution will done by `e` (evaluate string as an operator) modifier with ternary conditional operator.

```
$s = "text1 notation1";
$s=~s/(\w+)\s(\w+)/($2 eq "notation1")?"newtext1 $2":"$1  $2"/e;
print $s;
```